# Transistor gain vs circuit gain

Tags: transistors

In a CE circuit what happens when gain, determined by Rc/Re is greater than transistor beta?

i.e. I'm designing an amplifier for 75mhz, I have a 2nF capacitor across Re. I expect the impedance at that frequency to be 15ohm. My Rc is 2.5K , so Rc/Re = 166.

This is greater than beta for this particular transistor,
what actually happens under these conditions?

Comment: In the emitter-degenerate CE stage, Rc/Re is the (approximate) voltage gain. \$\beta\$ is the transistor's current gain. There's no reason these two things should be numerically comparable.

Comment: hFE only affects Ic/Ib not the I*Rc result.  so with voltage gain you lose on power from higher Rc

Comment: ok that's great I was expecting it to not be related but I felt I was gaining something for nothing. in electronics as in life this is hardly the case. the power trade-off ties in nicely cheers for that :)

Comment: Exactly how did you compute the impedance of your capacitor? Curious.

Comment: I'm a noob and might be wrong, but I used the reactance calculation Xc = 1/2piFC.... ahhh and I did it wrong, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete expression is:

G = hfe * Rc / (hie + (1+hfe)*Ze)    (1),

where Ze includes the effect of the added capacitor, that is

Ze = Re//Xce = Re / (1+jwReCe)       (2)

Now, in (1) with (1+hfe)*Ze >> hie, and simplifying hfe with 1+hfe, we have the said Rc/Ze expression. Let's assume that beta and hfe are the same thing.

Re stabilizes BJT biasing with emitter negative feedback, reducing at the same time the gain; the capacitor Ce in // to Re gives you back the gain at high frequency.

Ideally the gain may increase at will with increasing frequency and Ce reactance that is going to 0. However, when Ze becomes small, it is not true any longer that hie >> (1+hfe) * Ze, so that it is not true that the gain can increase at will above hfe.
Taking Ze to 0, the limit for the gain is hfe * Rc / hie = gm*Rc.

[Note: the gain in reality is negative for the 180° phase rotation of this configuration; its magnitude was considered above]